# Find Frequency Transfer Function

Tags: laplace-transform, transfer-theory

I have undamped oscilator which is described with following equation:

$$ \ddot{y}+\omega^2y=u $$

I need to find transfer function $$ H(s) $$ and freguency transfer function for  $$ H(j\omega) $$

..................................................................................................................................................................

I found transfer function, but I don't know how to make Frequency transfer function.  $$ H(s)=\frac{1}{s^2+\omega^2} $$

If I use this equation $$ p =j\omega $$ i get this:

$$ H(s)=\frac{1}{(j\omega)^2+\omega^2}= \frac{1}{-\omega^2+\omega^2}$$ 
Ang I guess this is not right result.

Thank you for advice.

Comment: You're a bit confused. The $\omega$ in your ODE is a constant, whereas the $\omega$ in the transform is a variable. I suggest you call the $\omega$ in your ODE $\omega_0$ instead to emphasize this and avoid the confusion.

Comment: Thank You. So the result is $$ H(j\omega) = \frac{1}{-\omega^2+\omega_0^2 }$$ ?

But there is no imaginary part, because  $$j^2=-1$$. What does it mean?

Comment: Yes, there is no imaginary part. So what? You have $H(j\omega) = -1/(\omega^2 - \omega_0^2)$. Thus if $|\omega| > |\omega_0|$ there is a phase shift of $\pi$ and if $|\omega| < |\omega_0|$ the phase shift is $0$. For $\omega = \omega_0$ the amplification is infinite.

Comment: Thank you very much for you advice.

Comment: Ok, no problem.

Answer (score 1):

To find:

$$\text{H}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{U}\left(\text{s}\right)}$$

Use Laplace transform:

$$\text{y}''(t)+\omega_\text{k}^2\cdot\text{y}(t)=\text{u}(t)\to\text{s}^2\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)-\text{s}\cdot\text{y}(0)-\text{y}'(0)+\omega_\text{k}^2\cdot\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)=\text{U}\left(\text{s}\right)$$

When we set all the initial conditions equal to $0$:

$$\text{s}^2\cdot\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)+\omega_\text{k}^2\cdot\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)=\text{U}\left(\text{s}\right)\Longleftrightarrow\frac{\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{U}\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{1}{\omega_\text{k}^2+\text{s}^2}$$

Where $\omega_\text{k}$ is the constant omega.

When we set $\text{s}=\text{j}\omega$ where $\text{j}^2=-1$:

$$\text{H}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{U}\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{1}{\omega_\text{k}^2+\left(\text{j}\omega\right)^2}=\frac{1}{\omega_\text{k}^2-\omega^2}$$